# Status bar Hide On Uploading Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

When I am uploading image from camera to my imageview Image sucessful upload but my status bar became hide. I am newer in iOS. Please HELP. Any i m setting in app delegate . They hide my status bar . Any help would be apperciated.

```
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];

and i m setting in info.plist  

    View controller-based status bar appearance  NO
    -(IBAction)choosePicture:(id)sender
    {
     imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.delegate=self;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];


    }
    -(IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender
    {
      imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.delegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
    {
        pickedImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(saveImage:) withObject:nil];

        image.image=pickedImage;
        pickedImage  =  [self compressImage:pickedImage];


        pickedImageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage,0.9);
                       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                   animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden   // also do this for iOS 8
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code.. Whatever you have done till now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about which iOS version you are takikng about. I experienced this in iOS 8.3, and this is how I solved it, inside your viewWillAppear method:

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    }
```

Add the above code to see if the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this code:

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                   animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

This function will be called when the navigation pop or push, or present or dismiss viewcontroller. If should check like this

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                   animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerViewController class]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    }
}
```